# HTML - Ordered List Not Numbering Properly

Tags: html, html-lists

I am trying to use HTML to:

- Create 2 Ordered Lists
- Within Each of the O.L. nest a Unordered List and add some elements inside

However, my numbering isn't working the way it should, I'm getting, *1. 1.* rather than *1. 2. etc.*

My code:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Fruits</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Plum</li>
    <li>Watermelon</li>
  </ul>
</ol> 
<ol>
  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Carrots</li>
    <li>Lettuce</li>
    <li>Cucumber</li>
    <li>Tomato</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

Comment: You cannot nest `ul` element inside `ol` as a direct child...

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you actually want 1 ordered list, not 2. If you expect the first one to have the number 1 and and the second one to have the number 2, that's one list. The numbers will reset if you start a new list.

```html
<ol>
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apples</li>
      <li>Oranges</li>
      <li>Plum</li>
      <li>Watermelon</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Vegetables
    <ul>
      <li>Carrots</li>
      <li>Lettuce</li>
      <li>Cucumber</li>
      <li>Tomato</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You cannot nest `ul` as a direct `ol` child

Comment: @Mr.Alien Maybe that's true according to the HTML spec but in practice browsers allow it. I just tested it. Nevertheless I changed my answer to the more correct nesting just now.

Comment: The question I am trying to tackle, says I require 2 OLs, with nested ULs

Comment: @GDesigns If you require 2 ordered lists, they will each begin with the number 1. But you require the 2nd ordered list to begin with 2. Your 2 requirements are in logical conflict with each other. If you want the numbers 1 and 2, you want 1 list.

Comment: @Asaph Browsers allow `<p>this as well</P>` doesn't mean we should use it :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien `<p></P>` is valid in HTML. But your point is right: a list can only have list items. Not doing that is invalid and sematically wrong.

Comment: @Oriol Yea, just chose a wrong example ... should've used an example like `<p><div>this is invalid</div></p>` but anyways, wanted to convey my point that though browsers allow loose codes doesn't mean we should be using them

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why everyone's answering against the docs, officially, you CANNOT nest `<ul>` element as a direct child to `<ol>` element and vice versa, so I've modified the markup accordingly.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jeohe8m/)

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h2>Fruits</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Oranges</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Vegetables</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Carrot</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Here, you can adjust the `padding` and `margin` of the unordered lists as required by you but I just gave a general idea of how it should be.

You can also use `<p>` or any other tag at the place of `<h2>` but I think `<h2>` or `<h3>` should fit well for your case.

Comment: "you CANNOT nest <ul> element as a direct child to <ol>" can you provide some evidence for that? The W3C validator doesn't seem to mind it, at least when it's contained within a <li>.

Comment: @Danack The content model of [`ol`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) elements is "Zero or more [`li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) and [script-supporting](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0) elements". That means that `ul` can't be a child of an `ol`, but can be a descendant.

Comment: @Danack As the spec says [`Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element)

Answer (score 1):

You're ending the ordered list after the first line. Don't put the  tag in untill the end of the entire ordered list. Example below.

```html
<ol>
  <li>Fruits</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Plum</li>
    <li>Watermelon</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Carrots</li>
    <li>Lettuce</li>
    <li>Cucumber</li>
    <li>Tomato</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't use the `list-style`-property but the `counter-increment`-property instead so your HTML stays as it is.

```css
ol {
  counter-increment: section;
}
ol > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol > li:before {
  content: counter(section)". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Fruits</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Plum</li>
    <li>Watermelon</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>Vegetables</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Carrots</li>
    <li>Lettuce</li>
    <li>Cucumber</li>
    <li>Tomato</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```